# What happens at the point whose differential is nonzero

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The question is:

> Suppose that $f$ is differentiable in $U = D(0;1)\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at $(0,0)$ is nonzero. Is it true that $f(x,y) \neq f(0,0)$ in some deleted neighborhood of $(0,0)$? If not, support an example.

Here the differential $f'(x,y)$ of $f$ at $(x,y)$ is a linear mapping from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that
$$ \lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \frac{|f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y) -f'(x,y)(h,k)|}{|(h,k)|} = 0. $$

What I have try so far is the following:
Suppose $f(0,0) = (0,0)$. If the question is not true, there exists a sequence $(h_n,k_n)$ converges to $(0,0)$ such that $f(h_n,k_n) = (0,0)$. So
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{|f'(0,0)(h_n,k_n)|}{|(h_n,k_n)|} = 0.
$$
Let $(a_n,b_n) = (h_n,k_n)/|(h_n,k_n)|$. Then $\{(a_n,b_n)\}$ is in the unit circle, which is compact, so there is a subsequence converging to $(a,b)$. So $f'(0,0)(a,b) = (0,0)$ if $f'(0,0)$ is continuous $(*)$. So the determinant of the Jabobian matrix at $(0,0)$ is $0$. I stuck here. Also, $(*)$ is my additional assumption, which may not true in general. So I am more trending to an counterexample.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: No: $f(x,y)=x$.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg: Oh, thank you so much! If the determinant of the Jacobian matrix is zero, it is likely $(1 0, 0 0)$ matrix, which leads to your example. :)

Comment: But isn't this a map into $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: @user99680: I think he means $f(x,y) = (x,0)$. :)

Comment: Dear Du Phan, sorry, I misread your question. But   your new interpretation $f(x,y)=(x,0)$   yields a valid  counterexample.   Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a non-zero differential is not sufficient to get what you want.

If you assume that the differential of $f$ at $0$ has rank $2$, then the local inversion theorem says that the map $f$ is a local diffeomorphism in a neighborhhod of $0$. In particular, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $(0,0)$ such that if $(x,y) \in U$ with $f(x,y) = f(0,0)$ then $(x,y) = (0,0)$ as you want.

If the differential at $0$ is not of rank $2$, you cannot say what you want. Simply consider $f(x,y) = (x,0)$.